# prisma deploy --env-file variables.env throwing an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, backend, prisma

When I run: prisma deploy --env-file variables.env

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the length my service's name (string) was too long. A shorter service name fixed it.